# Is ResultSet used by celery.group using the wrong method to `add` a result?

Tags: python, python-2.7, celery

Is `ResultSet` used by celery.group using the wrong method to `add` a result?

The version of celery I'm using is 3.0.24

### the gist

```
# primary celery module
celery = Celery(...)


# task module
from celery import current_app
@current_app.task(max_retries=5)
def get_page(url):
    # do stuff to "get page"
    return page


# program
from celery import group

url = "http://someurl"

if not groupresult:
    groupresult = group([get_page.s(url)]).apply_async()
else:
    async = get_page.delay(url)
    groupresult.add(async)
```

#### and the traceback this produces...

```
File "/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/result.py", line 308, in add
    self.results.append(result)
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'append'
```

#### The bottom of [this hastebin](http://hastebin.com/kurecotawa.py) has the associated celery source code

---

#### EDIT 0

Some additional info, in case it matters:

I'm actually starting my celery worker elsewhere, using `-P eventlet`, a redis broker, and a redis backend. I have been using this config for a while with success.

Also, updated the gist above to be more specific, using `current_app`.

---

#### EDIT 1

The issue lies in `celery/app/builtins.py`, around [here](https://github.com/celery/celery/blob/v3.0.24/celery/app/builtins.py#L200). I'd have to force `results` to be a list rather than a tuple before passing it to `GroupResult` to get this to work.

celery: [Grouping Tasks](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.html#grouping-tasks)

Comment: How did you get `groupresult`?

Comment: ```groupresult = group([get_page.s(url)]).apply_async()```

Comment: the first time through, `groupresult=None`, and it will execute the code to define `groupresult`. the second/third/nth time through, it will go into `else:`

Comment: It seems what even if documentation notice GroupResult is the same as ResultSet in fact they are have different behaviour. Here response from Celery maintainer: https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/1883